# XCode warning: 'NSString' may not respond to '-equals:'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, warnings

I'm getting the warning:

> 'NSString' may not respond to '-equals:'

and I can't figure out why `NSString` would ever not respond to `equals`. Is the compiler assuming that the elements in `anExpression` may not be `NSString`s?

```
+ (NSSet *)variablesInExpression:(id)anExpression
{
    NSMutableSet *setOfVariables = [[NSSet alloc] init];
    for (NSString *str in anExpression) {
        if (([str equals: @"x"] || [str equals: @"a"] || [str equals: @"b"])
            && ![setOfVariables member:str]) {
            [setOfVariables addObject:str];
        }
    }
    return setOfVariables;
    [setOfVariables release];   
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 4):

This is not [java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29). You should use the method [`isEqualToString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsstring_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-isEqualToString_).

```
if (([str isEqualToString:@"x"] || [str isEqualToString:@"a"] || [strisEqualToString: @"b"]) && ![setOfVariables member:str])
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I just did that. Thanks!